# jqGrid 5.1.0 "Warning" ("Please, select row") Dialog Appears On Page Load

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am building a new app using jqGrid 5.1.0.  When my page loads the grid displays as expected and contains the expected data.  However, immediately a "Warning" box appears with the text "Please, select row".  I can't close the Warning and I can't do anything with the rest of the page.

After thinking through the problem as well as Googling I suspected maybe the order in which I am loading .js and .css was the problem so I experimented with different orders but to no avail.

Here is what I am loading (paths altered for brevity but all .js loads and all .css is accessible)...

```
<script src="...jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="...jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="...grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="...jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...jquery-ui.structure.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...jquery-ui.theme.css" />
```

Maybe I am missing one or more of either.  Hard to say since, like I said, everything *appears* correct but I can't interact with the page.

Not sure what else to do.

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Can yous hare some of your jqgrid code? I know that message appears when some one tries to edit the grid.

Comment: Self-answered below.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: I can't imagine how a missing css could cause this issue.

Comment: Same here but that was the case.  I tried to narrow the problem done to one of the specific .css I added but it didn't matter one which one(s) I left - the problem was gone until all three were removed.  Strange.

Comment: It happens. Programming is magic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation I found I was missing .css for the grid.  *Oops!*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...ui.jqgrid-bootstrap-ui.css" />
```

Page now loads without the Warning appearing and the grid, based on initial testing, works as expected.